# Changing the way output file looks (C++) - Need to first read and then write in a different format

Tags: c++

I have a question in C++. I have saved a .dat file and it's currently being outputted as:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...... (2n columns, single spacing)

However, I want my .dat file to look something like: (n*2 matrix format, tab spacing)

> 1 2
>
> 3 4
>
> 5 6

Can anybody please help?

P.S. I am not able to update my file while writing in the first place because it is written in Palabos (An Open-source CFD solver) and I am outputting values as a 2-D Tensor. (My code to output .dat files (if required) ):

```
for (int iLevel = 0; iLevel<3; ++iLevel){
ofstream ofile("profile.dat");
std::auto_ptr< MultiTensorField2D< T, 2 > > vel = plb::computeVelocity  (lattice.getComponent(iLevel));
ofile << *vel << " ";} // here I'm using " " instead of endl;
```

edit: I can not use ofile << \t << *vel << \n because *vel outputs around 500 values in one iteration. Sorry about the confusion.

Thank you very much in advance. - Manas

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, just use '\t' for tab and '\n' for the newline.

Comment: Hi, @Dave Something, *vel outputs 500 values so if I use this approach, my output would look something like \t 1 2 3 ... 500 \n \t 501 502 503 ...\n \t 1001 .... I need to break *vel. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create a new line of text, just write `"\n"` or `endl` to the file. For spacing (using tab) write `"\t"` to the file. So it will look something like this:
`ofile << "\t" << *vel << "\n";`
That adds a space before the value and writes the next to a new line. Use this with some if statements to get the result you need.

Comment: Hi, @TheDoc, *vel outputs 500 values so if I use this approach, my output would look something like \t 1 2 3 ... 500 \n \t 501 502 503 ...\n \t 1001 .... I need to break *vel.